# What DNS MX setting should I use to control incoming mail from Plesk?

Tags: email, dns

I have a 1&1 VPS with Plesk, and a domain name with 123-Reg. I've configured my DNS records as such:

```
www a 87.106.101.240
mail a 87.106.101.240
mail.limehousecraftsandgifts.com. mx 10
```

From within Plesk, on the limehousecraftsandgifts.com domain, I've got a mail redirect for all email to go to my Gmail.  But the emails are not getting through.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? 87.106.101.240 is my server.

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Shad, I was able to investigate and realise that my DNS settings were correct. I was having a problem with Qmail on my VPS. The command line for Qmail said it was running fine, but the Plesk control panel would allow the service to start, but would then stop 20 seconds later.  Ultimately, the problem was a misconfigured Qmail. So check your mail logs, and your Qmail status if you're having this problem.

I'm leaving this here as a note to anyone encountering similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you don't have an `A RECORD` for `mail.limehouecraftsandgifts.com` =)

You should point it where-ever you want the mail delivered.

Comment: The formatting of my question was poor, I've updated it.  There is an "a" record for mail, it's on the second line as shown above.

Comment: ah ic. Do you know for sure you have mail hosting turned on in your Plesk interface for the domain? (I've had a reverse problem of having it turned on when I dont want it on)

Comment: That's an interesting question. I'll call 1&1 and ask them.  I'll let you know when I do. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Annoyingly, they say everything is setup correctly, and I should check the mail logs.  I'm desperately trying this.